# Confusion with Scanners (Big Java Ex 6.3)

Tags: java

Currently reading Chapter 6 in my book. Where we introduce for loops and while loops.

Alright So basically The program example they have wants me to let the user to type in any amount of numbers until the user types in Q. Once the user types in Q, I need to get the max number and average.

I won't put the methods that actually do calculations since I named them pretty nicely, but the main is where my confusion lies.

By the way Heres a simple input output

**Input**

```
10
0
-1
Q
```

**Output**

```
Average = 3.0
Max = 10.0
```

**My code**

```
public class DataSet{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        DataAnalyze data = new DataAnalyze();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        while(!done)
        {

            String result = input.next();
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                double x = inputTwo.nextDouble();
                data.add(x);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Average = " + data.getAverage());
        System.out.println("Max num = " + data.getMaximum());
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error at `double x = inputTwo.nextDouble();`.

Heres my thought process.

Lets make a flag and keep looping asking the user for a number until we hit `Q`. Now my issue is that of course the number needs to be a double and the `Q` will be a string. So my attempt was to make two scanners

Heres how my understanding of  scanner based on chapter two in my book.

Alright so `import Scanner` from `java.util library` so we can use this package. After that we have to create the `scanner` object. Say `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`. Now the only thing left to do is actually ASK the user for input so we doing this by setting this to another variable (namely `input` here). The reason this is nice is that it allows us to set our Scanner to `doubles` and `ints` etc, when it comes as a default `string` ( via `.nextDouble(), .nextInt()`);

So since I set result to a `string,` I was under the impression that I couldn't use the same `Scanner` object to get a `double`, so I made another `Scanner` Object named `inputTwo`, so that if the user doesn't put `Q` (i.e puts numbers) it will get those values.

How should I approach this? I feel like i'm not thinking of something very trivial and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path here, however you do not need two scanners to process the input. If the result is a number, cast it to a double using `double x = Double.parseDouble(result)` and remove the second scanner all together. Good Luck!

Comment: That converts it into a double correct?, why not just do double x = (double) result. I remember converting stuff by putting (double) , (int) at the front.

Comment: @cresjoy what you described is casting, and works between number types, but the parseDouble function is needed to convert a string.

Comment: ahh I see thanks! Looks like there is alot of syntax to learn :(

Comment: @cresjoy You don't have any new syntax to learn here. Double.parseDouble() is just a method call. You already know the syntax for method calls since you're already using methods. All you need to know are the casting rules, and when they're not applicable. You can only cast between similar types, e.g. between numeric types. A string is not at all similar to a number. So you need to pass it to a function that will convert it to a number for you.

Comment: Totally makes sense. Thank you!